# Match Regular Expressions for Exclude List in deja-dup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, dconf

It appears deja-dup does not accept regular expressions when adding entries via dconf-editor to org.gnome.DejaDup.exclude-list. Is there a solution to allow for regex matching of paths for this parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, regular expressions aren't supported by deja-dup and there is no workaround currently.  You'll need to specify the folders explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't support regular expressions, you can exclude specific folders by adding a .deja-dup-ignore file in the folder. Here is a script which will go and add this file to any matching folders, defined below as 'ignoreFolder'. Customize as needed. Note that the example below is ignoring 'node_modules' folders, but it won't go deeper than the first parent node_modules folder it finds in any hierarchy (ie. it won't add it recursively under their child dependencies, because it doesn't need to). The mindepth/maxdepth there is only to speed up the find, but feel free to remove.

> To customize:
>
> -change startPath to the folder you want the script to run from (ie. /home/rw3iss/Sites)
>
> -change ignoreFolder to the folder pattern you want ignored (ie. node_modules')
>
> -if you don't need it to ignore sub-dependency directories, just remove the '-not -regex ".*$ignoreFolder.*$ignoreFolder.*"' bit.
>
> ```
> startPath=/home/rw3iss/Sites
> ignoreFolder=node_modules
>
> find $startPath -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 5 -name "$ignoreFolder" -type d -not -regex ".*$ignoreFolder.*$ignoreFolder.*" | while read fname; do
>   echo "" > "$fname/.deja-dup-ignore"
>   echo "$fname/.deja-dup-ignore created."
> done
> ```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/rw3iss/1db5d19a85470f2646ee2a1da1cf9fc5

Comment: Thanks for stumbling across this very old question with a new and relevant answer :) This might help some who are at least looking for a partial workaround.

Comment: Aye! Couldn't find a solution myself, stumbled... solved... ;-)